# Implement Page-Object models in C# Selenium - PageFactory

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nunit

I am very new to the test automation.

1. I run Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.6.2
2. I have NuGet packages: Selenium.WebDriver, Selenium.Support, Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver,
   Gherkin, NUnit, NUnit3TestAdapter, xunit, BoDi, SpecFlow.Internal.Json

I try to implement the POM model testing using an example I found on the web.

**POM:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace POMExample.PageObjects
{
    internal class HomePage
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = ".fusion-main-menu a[href*='about']")]
        private IWebElement about;

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "fusion-main-menu-icon")]
        private IWebElement searchIcon;

        public void goToPage()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.swtestacademy.com");
        }

        public AboutPage goToAboutPage()
        {
            about.Click();
            return new AboutPage(driver);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using POMExample.PageObjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace POMExample
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [Test]
        public void SearchTextFromAboutPage()
        {
            HomePage home = new HomePage(driver);
            home.goToPage();
            AboutPage about = home.goToAboutPage();
            ResultPage result = about.search("selenium c#");
            result.clickOnFirstArticle();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However POM Indicates errors:

The type or namespace name 'PageObjects' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support'

The name 'PageFactory' does not exist in the current context

etc...

see the screenshot below:

[image]

using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

Do I understand it right PageFactory is deprecated now ?
Is it the reason?
What can I use instead?
Can somebody give me a link, advice, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - Selenium "PageFactory" is deprecated as of v3.11:

> https://ultimateqa.com/selenium-3-11-released/
>
> PageFactory in C# is deprecated as of version 3.11. This is actually a
> great change because it prevents usage of a class that is not
> recommended by the Selenium contributors. Furthermore, not using
> PageFactory will prevent users from many weird element exceptions that
> aren’t experienced when using a simple runtime element locator.

The link continues:

> This in no way means that you should stop using Page Objects Pattern.
> This is totally a separate concept. You can use Page Object Pattern
> without the PageFactory.cs. The latter is just a Selenium
> implementation that has no relation with a design pattern.

Finally:

> Avoiding PageFactory is very simple using [Acceptance Test Driven
> Automation](https://ultimateqa.com/acceptance-test-driven-automation/).
> Here’s an example of a class that meets all [Page Object best
> practices](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/6-rules-high-quality-page-object-patterns):
>
> ```
> public class ProductsPage : BasePage
> {
>     private readonly string _pageUrlPart;
>
>     public ProductsPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
>     {
>         _pageUrlPart = "inventory.html";
>     }
>
>     // An element can be located using ExpectedConditions through an explicit wait
>     public bool IsLoaded => Wait.UntilIsDisplayedById("inventory_filter_container");
>
>     //elements are not accessible for the external test API
>     private IWebElement LogoutLink => _driver.FindElement(By.Id("logout_sidebar_link"));
>
>     // An element can also be located without ExpectedConditions
>     private IWebElement HamburgerElement => _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bm-burger-button"));
>
>     public int ProductCount =>
>         _driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("inventory_item")).Count;
>
>     //We are using Composition to have one page object living in another page object
>     public CartComponent Cart => new CartComponent(_driver);
>
>     public void Logout()
>     {
>         HamburgerElement.Click();
>         LogoutLink.Click();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Also: see this link: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38673/56737

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4 , what libray I need to install to have "; BasePage" I have an error when I try to use : BasePage - the type could not be found. Is it any special package I need to install ?

Comment: Ok, thank you @paulsm4 Upvoting is added I found the answer helpful.